# Grouping in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have no idea at the moment how I can write this SQL statement for SQL Server.

I have 2 tables:

**Customer**:

```
ID | Name   | Prename
----------------------
1    Miller   Thomas
....
```

**Steps**:

```
ID | FK_customer | step | created
------------------------------------
1    1             A      2010-02-03
2    1             B      2011-09-12
....
```

If I try to join it, I get this:

```
Name   | A_date     | B_date
----------------------------------
Miller   2010-02-03   NULL
Miller   NULL         2011-09-12
```

What I want is this:

```
Name   | A_date     | B_date
---------------------------------
Miller   2010-02-03   2011-09-12
```

Can anybody show me the light?

Comment: Show us your query.

Comment: do you only have 1 date per date column per name? (or in the case of multiples, will grabbing the top one be sufficient?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
SELECT c.Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN step = 'A' THEN created END) AS A_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN step = 'B' THEN created END) AS B_date
FROM customer c
JOIN steps s ON c.Id = s.FK_customer
GROUP BY c.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.Name, A.A_date, B.B_date
FROM Customer c
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT MAX(created) AS A_date
    FROM steps s
    WHERE s.FK_customer  = c.Id
    AND s.step = 'A'
)AS A
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT MAX(created) AS B_date
    FROM steps s
    WHERE s.FK_customer  = c.Id
    AND s.step = 'B'
)B
```

Comment: its more complicated than the question but for the effort will give you 1 vote. :)